# Set exposed filter date programmatically

Tags: 7, views

I would like to programmatically set an exposed filter for a field date (field_date) in a view.

Date has to be > of a specific date or between to dates.

I tried this, but it does not work. It ignores the filter.

```
$view = views_get_view('myview');
$view->set_display("default");
$view->get_exposed_input();

$exposed_filters["field_date_value_op "] = "between";

$exposed_filters["field_date_value"]["value"]["day"] = "";
$exposed_filters["field_date_value"]["value"]["month"] = "";
$exposed_filters["field_date_value"]["value"]["year"] = "";

$exposed_filters["field_date_value"]["min"]["day"] = 1;
$exposed_filters["field_date_value"]["min"]["month"] = 1;
$exposed_filters["field_date_value"]["min"]["year"] = 2014;

$exposed_filters["field_date_value"]["max"]["day"] = 1;
$exposed_filters["field_date_value"]["max"]["month"] = 12;
$exposed_filters["field_date_value"]["max"]["year"] = 2015;

$view->set_exposed_input($exposed_filters);
$view->execute();
```

Any idea? Thank you in advance.

Comment: In "Date has to be > of a specific date or between to dates. " You mean larger from a specific date between two dates?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below after set_display line.

```
function mymodule_views_pre_view(&$view) {
  if ($view->name == 'myview_user'){
    $view->get_exposed_input();
    dsm($view->exposed_input['created']['min']);
    $view->exposed_input['created']['min'] = "2015-01-01";
    $view->exposed_input['created']['max'] = "2016-01-01";

    //$view->set_exposed_input($exposed_filters);
    $view->execute();
  }
}
```

Please refer the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27917360/unable-to-programmatically-set-exposed-filter-for-date-in-views-drupal-7)

Comment: thank you, but I'm sorry, I cannot understand how to use this in my case.
display-name = default
What I have to write instead of filter? and instead of filter_1_id?

Comment: filter_1_id would your filter or field id which you want to filter the data

Comment: that works in general, but not for the case I described

Comment: Please review my answer again. I have edited the answer with filters for Users table with created field.